# second fragment doesn't appear

Tags: android

Vertical layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="john.unitconverter.UnitConverter">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/unitConverter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="john.unitconverter.ConverterFragment"></fragment>


</RelativeLayout>
```

horizontal layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/unitConverter"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="john.unitconverter.ConverterFragment"></fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/discConverter"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="john.unitconverter.DisclaimerFragment"></fragment>


</LinearLayout>
```

what's inside the second fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="john.unitconverter.DisclaimerFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
        android:text="landscape mode is missing some features." />
</FrameLayout>
```

what happens is the second fragment doesn't show in landscape. why is that happening? basically, only the first fragment is showing up in the screen both horizontal and vertical layout.

thanks

Comment: Apply weight to fragments tag. And why dont you add fragments dynamically. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment you have to use the weight attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/discConverter"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.trist_000.teststack.ArticleFragment"></fragment>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/unitConverter"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.trist_000.teststack.ArticleFragment"></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
    android:text="landscape mode is missing some features." />
</FrameLayout>
```

The result:

[image: res]

Comment: i copied that code and still the second fragment doesn't show on the screen.

Comment: Can you edit your post with DisclaimerFragmen and ConverterFragment layout

Comment: in vertical it should only be one fragment but in landscape mode there should be 2 fragments. i'm still stuck in here, i edited my post. can you check again ty.